# I'm trying to change the Rectangle colour to Black but its not working

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm new to `Java` and don't know exactly what the cause.Let me explain the **issue**

I created a Rectangle Shape and its working, then i thought about changing its color to black for some testing but it seems not working below is my code.
When i call the method from `paintComponent` itself then its working but if i do the same from any other method then its not changing the color. I tried calling the method repaint also but still the same

```
public class Meme extends JPanel {

Rectangle2D.Float myRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(90, 90, 90, 90);
Graphics2D graphics2d;

public void DRAW() {
    graphics2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 200));
    graphics2d.fill(myRect);
}

public void ChangeColour() {
    System.out.println("Called");
    graphics2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    System.out.println("Called2");
    graphics2d.fill(myRect);
    System.out.println("Called3");
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    DRAW();
}
```

}

Button click listener method

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    meme1.ChangeColour();
}
```

Comment: you need to call changecolor function

Comment: yes i called it from paintComonent its working.. But doesn't working when i call the method from another funtion

Comment: All painting should be done from within the `paintComponent` method. The idea is you change the state (ie color) and call `repaint` to trigger a new paint pass

Comment: call function change color in paintcompnent

Comment: @MadProgrammer sir is there any way of making this work ? i want to add button to Swing GUi when use click the button rectangle should change to black ? Sir please help

Comment: @WaleedAsim yes sir it worked...But my problem is something different i want to call change the color to black when user hits a jButton

Comment: @ArghaDas show me your code with jbutton click listener

Comment: @WaleedAsim sir i updated please look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can remember, whenever you change some properties (color in this case), you have to call repaint. This will invoke a call to paintComponent and the frame will be drawn once again.

In your case, I am guessing even if you call repaint after changing color, the DRAW method gets called again in paintComponent which resets the changed color back to (0, 0, 200). Therefore, you don't see any change in the screen. But when you call changeColor in paintComponent method (assuming after the call to DRAW), the change of color persists and does not get overridden.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Just keep the color stored somewhere else. Like

```
Color myColor = new Color(0,0,200);
```

then in DRAW:

```
private void DRAW() {
    graphics2d.setColor(myColor);
    graphics2d.fill(myRect);
}
```

and in ChangeColor:

```
private void ChangeColour() {
    myColor = Color.BLACK;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'll update the code and post here sir :) thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

update your function like this

```
public void ChangeColour() {
    System.out.println("Called");
    graphics2d.setColor(new Color(1, 1, 200));
    System.out.println("Called2");
    graphics2d.fill(myRect);
    System.out.println("Called3");
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) for quick response

Comment: when i hit positive some popup is triggered sir, Thanks for your feedbacl! Votes cast by those with less than 15reputation are recorder but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: if it solve your problem then up vote it and mark as solution :)

Comment: Not the down voter - but, how is this different what the OP is using? It's also an inappropriate method for painting in Swing, as painting should only occur within the context of a `paint` method. Apart from been possible to generate a `NullPointerException`, the next time the component is painted, any changes made within this method will be lost. If you're interested, see [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 0):

Painting in Swing is both passive and destructive.  That is, a paint pass can occur at anytime for any number of reasons, many which you don't control.  Destructive means, on each paint pass you are expected to repaint the entire component from scratch.

In Swing, you update the state you want change and then call `repaint` to trigger a new paint pass.

Painting should only ever paint the current state, it should never try and change it

```
public class Meme extends JPanel {

    Rectangle2D.Float myRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(90, 90, 90, 90);
    private Color color;

    public void draw(Graphics2D graphics2d) {
        graphics2d.setColor(color);
        graphics2d.fill(myRect);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public void ChangeColour() {
        color = Color.BLACK;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        draw(graphics2d);
        graphics2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Also, the graphics context passed to your component is shared with all the other components, so it's important that any significant changes you make to the context are undone before the method exists - in most cases, it's just a simple case of calling `create` on the `Graphics` context to snapshot it state and `dispose` (on the copy you created) when you're done